# what exit codes does gdb return on executing the next program line after one types the 'next' command?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, return-code

In a linux terminal, I typed the command *why* (this command does not exist), and got this response

```
No command 'why'found, did you mean:
 ....
why: command not found
```

to get the exit code, this is what I typed in:

```
$?
```

and got the response:

```
127: command not found
```

I am assuming that when most of the commands run, they return codes.
Now with gdb, after it executes the next line of the C program being debugged, does it return any codes? And if so, how do I get those codes (a command like *$?* in gdb? - I haven't found a documentation in *man gdb* pages of such a command.

*In any case, gdb should know (and probably log) whether the line executed successfully and if not, what went wrong.

Comment: When a target process finishes, gdb stores the exit code in the convenience variable `$_exitcode`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. But before the target process finishes, "there is only a state change in the program" as @dbush explained below - that answered what I had hoped to be answered in the first part of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a line of code executing successfully, at least not in same way that commands given to the shell do.

When you're at the shell, you're inputting either the name of an internal shell command or an external program.  In the case of an external program, the value of `$?` is the value the program passed to the `exit` system call.  If the shell can't find a program or command with that name, it gives you the error message you described.

In a compiled C program, there are no "codes" returned after a statement runs.  There is only a state change in the program.  For example, if a statement is `i = i + 1;`, then the value of `i` is 1 greater than its value prior to the statement running.

Answer (score 1):

Unix processes always return a value: their exit code; named such because most of programs terminate with a call to `exit` (there is other possibilities but with no importance here). Beware that **all** processes return such a code, not *most of them*. Shells interpret user typed lines and transform them into processes. When a process terminates, the shel let you know the value of the return code of the last process that it controlled. In bash this variable is `$?`. If you want to print it, you can use `echo $?`. If you type `$?` it will interpret it as a command but `127` (the exit value of the last command) is not a command. The standard is to have a return value of 0 for correctly terminated processes, and any non nul value to signal that an error occurred somewhere in the logic of the program.

gdb also launch processes (to control them) but, executing a single line of code, is not running a process, so there is no exit code after executing one step of a program code. When you execute, in gdb, something that terminates the process its exit code is available in a internal gdb variable `$_exitcode`.

Comment: Thank you @Jean-Baptiste. Thanks about the echoing of _$?_ to get its value as opposed to letting the shell use its value as a command when used without the echo. I oversaw that , thanks.